# Input desde datos entregados por un usb en c++

Tags: c++, usb

mi duda es sencilla y trata sobre leer los datos que llegan desde un USB al computador desde un lector de código de barras, la cosa es que nunca antes había usado un input de ese tipo y quería saber como se hace ya que siempre e usado de input el teclado, pensé que seria como rb3 en pero con puertos USB pero la verdad creo que no ya que no encentro nada de información por internet.

Gracias de ante mano <3

Comment: Pues dependerá del lector ... Si el que usas emula un teclado, pues lo tienes fácil. En otro caso ... pues a buscar en la documentación del fabricante.

Comment: Secundo lo dicho por @Trauma. Yo todos los que he tenido que manejar enviaban los datos por el buffer del teclado

Comment: Osea si pongo por ejemplo un `cin>>x` y utilizo el lector me devolverá el dato y lo podre guardar? Claro si simula un teclado y el tipo de dato esta bien

Comment: Eso es, así es como debería funcionar.